# grails mysql datatime file values come with T and Z

Tags: mysql, grails

I am quering mysql table in grails using custome select command, for datetime filed its includes T and Z. how can I remove this value?

```
2013-04-09T23:42:20Z
```

I need like this:

```
2013-04-09 23:42:20
```

Comment: It looks like you also get back the timezone information. Why not use a DateFormat to parse the Date?

Comment: php won't add this why grails adding this, like to fix it in the select statement itself, so I can use generic select sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are encoding your resultset as JSON. If you want your dates to be globally formatted, you probably want to do something like this in your `Bootstrap.groovy`:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {
    return it?.format("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the `date` as
`def newFormattedDate = date.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`

You are getting the standard date/timestamp format from database.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see such format? You get **date** from sql select, so use [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=406) for example to format as you wish.